# Extraction of subsequences that end with point and space by regular expression

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

hy
I want to extract sub sentences of this sentence by regular expression:

`it learn od fg network layout. kdsjhuu ddkm networ.12kfdf. learndfefe layout. learn sdffsfsfs. sddsd learn fefe.`

I couldn't write a correct regular expression for `Pattern.compile`.

This is my expression:`([^(\\.\\s)]*)([^.]*\\.)`

Actually, i need a way for writing "read everthing except `\\.\\s`

sub sentences:

- `it learn od fg network layout.`
- `kdsjhuu ddkm networ.12kfdf.`
- `learndfefe layout.`
- `learn sdffsfsfs.`
- `sddsd learn fefe.`

Comment: Why not just use String.split? For example > sentance.split(". ")

Comment: In what way is that regex not working?

Comment: the problem is in this part: "networ.12kfdf."

Comment: I don't need split. I want to use Matcher and then find .

Answer (score 0):

Just split your string with regex `"\\. "`

```
 String[] arr= str.split("\\. ");
```

Comment: I want to use this pattern in Matcher and then find it in a sentence .  Matcher m = pattern.matcher(sentence); 
             while(m.find())

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern with the `find` method:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^\\s.][^.]*(?:\\.(?!\\s|\\z)[^.]*)*\\.?");
Matcher m = p.matcher(yourText);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

Pattern details:

```
[^\\s.]             # all that is not a whitespace (to trim) or a dot
[^.]*               # all that is not a dot (zero or more times)
(?:                 # open a non-capturing group
    \\. (?!\\s|\\z) # dot not followed by a whitespace or the end of the string
    [^.]*           # 
)*                  # close and repeat the group as needed
\\.?                # an optional dot (allow to match a sentence at the end
                    # of the string even if there is no dot)
```

Comment: This is my answer.Thanks

Comment: Excuse me, I'm begginer in regular expression. If i want to find sentences contain for example "learn" or "learn ...network" in this sentence,what should i do?